# Full Screen Gallery with finger switch

Tags: android

I'd like to have a full screen gallery with a different set of pictures wich will be opend when I press some button.

I have searched a while for it, but I can't find something nice. Maybe someone of you can help me with some example.

Till now I have an app which includes a tab menü and under each tab there're are some buttons. now I'd like to open a full screen gallery with a specific set of pictures when I press a specific button. the gallerie shout be able to switch to the next picture by moving the fingers on the screen and have a progress bar under the picture to see how much pictures are in the gallery.

Is it possible to have one java class which implements the gallery and I pass the specific picture set over when I press the button. So I can store all picutres in an array.

The gallery shouldnt have a thumbnail picutres, just the main picutre

Example:

```
Tab1 | Tab2 

Button1

Button2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this project. 
https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery  in this gallery is loaded from some urls and the image in the gallery is with full image and the sliding between the images are using finger touch. you can zoom the pictures as well. you will be having library and sample project in that . Have a try with this. hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks, i will have a look at it later this day. if anyone else have some additional source it would be nice :)

Comment: ok now think your link doessnt help me. i would like to have an array, which is the storage for my pictures wich are in the drawable folder ... if a press the button, the first picture in the array will be shown and when i switch over the screen the next picture will be shown... hope anyone can help